# graph theory - maximal graph without cycles and maximal planar graph without triangles

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

> Let there be $G = (V,E_1\cup E_2)$ such that $(V,E_1)$ is a planar graph without triangles, and $(V,E_2)$ is without circles, show that $G$ is $6$-colorable

Can I prove here that $E_1$ and $E_2$ has at least one edge that is inside both of them when the vertices are $v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots,v_n$, I couldn't find why this is wrong, can someone please show it using the pigeon hole principle.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138289/discussion-on-question-by-elay-dadon-graph-theory-maximal-graph-without-cycles).